# Perl Mail::Sendmail cant connect to SMTP server

Tags: perl, smtp, sendmail

I'm trying to send an email from a perl script but I'm having a bad time connecting to my SMTP server. I'm using MailCatcher- https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/ - running with it's default settings (localhost:1025).

MailCatcher is running and I can send mail to it with other services. Any clues as to what could be wrong? (Also tried sending a mail with Net::SMTP but that also failed to connect)

```
print "Testing Mail::Sendmail version $Mail::Sendmail::VERSION\n";

my %mail = (
  To      => 'temp@test.com',
  From    => 'test@test.com',     
  Subject => 'Test message'
);

$mail{server} = 'localhost:1025';

$mail{'mESSaGE : '} = "The message key looks terrible, but works.";

print Dumper(%mail);

if (sendmail %mail) { print "Mail sent OK.\n" }
else { print "Error sending mail: $Mail::Sendmail::error \n" }
```

Output

```
Testing Mail::Sendmail version 0.79
Default server: localhost
Default sender: 
$VAR1 = 'Subject';
$VAR2 = 'Test message';
$VAR3 = 'server';
$VAR4 = 'localhost:1025';
$VAR5 = 'To';
$VAR6 = 'temp@test.com';
$VAR7 = 'message : ';
$VAR8 = 'The message key looks terrible, but works.';
$VAR9 = 'From';
$VAR10 = 'test@test.com';
Error sending mail: connect to localhost failed (Connection refused)
connect to localhost failed
connect to localhost failed (Connection refused)
connect to localhost failed
connect to localhost failed (Connection refused) no (more) retries!
```

EDIT:

Turned out mailcatcher was running on another port and wasn't giving an error when I was trying to start it up on 25.

Comment: MailCatcher runs the SMTP server on 1025 by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't set the mail server and port in a header within the email; rather you set it in the `%mailcfg` hash:

```
use Mail::Sendmail qw(sendmail %mailcfg)
$mailcfg{port} = 1025; #localhost is already the default server...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one .. it worked for me ..

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail); 
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP(); 
use Email::Simple();   
use Email::Simple::Creator();       

my $smtpserver = 'server';
my $smtpport = 25;      
my $smtpuser = 'User_Name';   
my $smtppassword = 'pass';         
my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new({   
    host => $smtpserver,  
    port => $smtpport,            
    sasl_username => $smtpuser,       
    sasl_password => $smtppassword,   
});            

my $email = Email::Simple->create(header => [
        To      => 'me@example.com',
        From    => 'sender@example.com',
        Subject => 'Hello there!',
    ],  body => "This is one actually worked !!\n",             
);             

sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
?>
```